# ¿Como selecciono solo un dato de una lista de registros con datos repetidos?

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy buscando la manera de mostrar solo el primer dato de cada registro que tenga mi tabla.

Tengo una tabla llamada `detalle_cuota` en la que:

- inserto el monto de cada cuota
- los montos segun la cantidad de cuotas que le diga que va a tener el curso
- cada 3 registros hace un aumento del 20% del monto anterior.

El problema es que cuando voy a procesar el primer pago necesito que me aparezca automaticamente el primer monto de las cuotas pertenecientes a ese curso.

Estas son las tablas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que busco hacer es que me aparezca en el formulario al momento de procesar el primer pago, el monto 1 y si es pagado que cambie algo a pagado. Y asi sucesivamente me vayan saliendo los montos que le toca pagar al estudiante.

**Algo asi deberia ser mi formulario.**

Ej: Curso: COMIDA, PRIMER PAGO: 44.000,

Ej: Curso: PASTELERIA, PRIMER PAGO: 66.000

Ej: Curso: COMIDA, SEGUNDO PAGO: 44.000

Comment: Que tal nuevamente Luis, primero unas preguntas. Como esta definida completamente la tabla de montos!? Sería de mucha ayuda si la compartes completamente y otra cosa, me dices que solo quieres mostrar el primer monto a pagar, pero que pasará despues cuando quieras el segundo!? o el primero si no ha sido pagado, veo necesaria una columna "pagado" del tipo boolean y una fecha de pago por si acaso. Saludos!

Comment: Saludos Rostan, voy a mostrar la imagen de las tablas en relacion a los cursos, cantidad de cuotas y montos. Y si en eso habia pensado que necesito ese campo pagado tipo boolean. Mostrare las tablas.

Comment: Alli muestro las 3 tablas en relacion Rostan, no se si me sugieres que modifique la relacion entre ellas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listo la consulta que necesitas es la siguiente:

```
SELECT TOP(1) C.curso, B.id_cuota, B.monto  --  Seleccionamos el primer registro(Necesitas el Order para que funcione)
FROM DETALLE_CUOTA AS B
INNER JOIN CUOTAS AS A
    ON (A.ID = B.ID)
INNER JOIN CURSOS_ABIERTOS AS C
    ON (A.id_curso = C.id)
WHERE A.id_curso = "CursoQueBuscas" --  Tu curso a buscar
    AND B.estado = false    --  Solo los que no estan pagados.
ORDER BY C.curso, B.id_cuota ASC    --  Ordenamos el resultado
```

Recuerda especificar el "CursoQueBuscas" y [B.Estado] usarlo en la condición como lo que represente para ti, true - pagado, false - no. Saludos!

Comment: Una pregunta Rostan el TOP (1) es para que me limitar el numero de filas devueltas no? si no me equivoco.

Comment: Exactamente! como lo ordeno de menor a mayor en la columna B.id_cuota , me traerá el registro que toque (ya que pede ser el 1, 2,3 ... etc).

Comment: Gracias Rostan, me ha funcionado.

Comment: No olvides marcar la respuesta como la que te sirvio, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

**Buen día**

Dependiendo como tengas totalmente pensado tu estructura; en relación a lo único que pones te sugiero le agregues un campo más por ejemplo `pagado` que será un flag mediante el cual identifiques cual ya fue realizado, tal que lo tengas en falso si aún no se ha recibido y verdadero en caso que sí.

Con el cambio que te sugiero será que conforme a `id_cuota` (asumo identifica si es comida, pasteleria, etc...) sería por ejemplo para obtener el siguiente a cubrir:

```
SELECT ID, ID_CUOTA, MONTO FROM [TU TABLA QUE MUESTRAS]
WHERE ID (SELECT MIN(ID) 
          FROM [TU TABLA QUE MUESTRAS] WHERE PAGADO=0 
          and ID_CUOTA=[IDENTIFICADOR DE AQUIEN CORRESPONDE LA CUOTA])
      and ID_CUOTA=[IDENTIFICADOR DE AQUIEN CORRESPONDE LA CUOTA]
```

Espero te sirva.

**EDITADO**

```
SELECT cuotaPagar.ID, cuotaPagar.ID_CUOTA, cuotaPagar.MONTO 
FROM [TU TABLA QUE MUESTRAS] as cuotaPagar
WHERE cuotaPagar.ID (SELECT MIN(cuotaxPagar.ID) 
          FROM [TU TABLA QUE MUESTRAS] cuotaxPagar
          WHERE cuotaxPagar.PAGADO=0 
          and cuotaxPagar.ID_CUOTA=cuotaPagar.ID_CUOTA)
      and cuotaPagar.ID_CUOTA=[IDENTIFICADOR DE AQUIEN CORRESPONDE LA CUOTA]
```

o prueba con solo

```
SELECT cuotaPagar.ID, MIN(cuotaPagar.ID_CUOTA) as ID_CUOTA, cuotaPagar.MONTO 
FROM [TU TABLA QUE MUESTRAS] as cuotaPagar
WHERE cuotaPagar.PAGADO=0
      and cuotaPagar.ID_CUOTA=[IDENTIFICADOR DE AQUIEN CORRESPONDE LA CUOTA]
```

Comment: Saludos Roberto, si hare lo del campo booleano, ahora lo unico que tengo duda es en el segundo select ese MIN ( ID ) es para que vaya seleccionando el menor de la tabla donde el campo pagado = 0 y el id de la cuota = id_curso al que pertenece esa cuota, ya el segundo AND si no lo entiendo Roberto